# Odoo 11 is not printing PDF report with 20.000 lines of issued invoices, but it does with 10.000

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf

Odoo v11, on my dev machine, is not printing a custom pdf report with 20.000 lines of issued invoices (one line per invoice).

I tested the printing with different amount of invoices from 1.000 to 10.000 lines with success. In fact, 10.000 lines of invoices takes about 2-3 minutes to print.
Any of the subsequent tests from 11.000 to 20.000 lines of invoices doesn't print (only appears the loading message for a long time, even hours with no results).

Report has not images. Only has a table with lines, a header and footer. The test of 10.000 lines of invoices results in a report with 350 pages. But, when I test with 11.000 lines of invoices or higher it doesn't work.
Printing so many data is important for us for printing entire year invoicing or VAT books for current year.

The specs of my dev machine are Core i5-3330 3.00GHz, 12 GB RAM DDR3 1333 MHz and SATA 3 hard drive.

Any suggestions on how to improve the performance of wkhtmltopdf to render tons of data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 10000 invoices on 350 pages? Sorry WTF? Actually i wasn't aware that wkhtmltopdf can generate that many invoices.

Comment: Well, clear out that is a custom report with one line per invoice. It´s like a summary report.

Comment: The only sensible answer I can give to "doesn't work" is: "make it work" ‍♂️. If you want anybody to help in anything else, give details on the problem: debugging traces, error messages, source code of the report, etc.

Comment: The version of wkhtmltopdf would be a nice info, too. `wkhtmltopdf -V` into terminal will show it.

Comment: The version is wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4

Comment: I asked the same question In Odoo help webpage and someone suggested me to set **limit_time_real** parameter in odoo-server.conf file to 6000 seconds (default is 120 seconds wich makes sense because 10.000 lines is working and takes about 2 minutes). I will try setting this parameter and I will comment the results.

Comment: Well, finally I've tested running wkhtmltopdf command directly from terminal with the HTML file generated by Odoo located in tmp folder as input file parameter. The test was made with 11.500 lines of invoices and it took 2-3 seconds to generate the PDF. So, my personal conclussion is the problem seems to be related with generating styling or ensambling the different parts of PDF report (header, body and footer).